# OpenGL Rending multiple triangle strips results in gaps

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am in the midst of my first foray into OpenGL using C++ and Qt as the supporting cast.

In what amounts to my playground for implementing a feature outside of the main application, I am attempting to draw what amounts to a mesh surface from a two-dimensional array of floats. The indices of this 2d array are used for the x and z coordinates and the value is the y coordinate.

Currently my implementation is bugged. Instead of creating a solid surface there are noticeable black gaps.

A quick Google showed me http://marc.blog.atpurpose.com/2009/10/24/programatically-generating-a-rectangular-mesh-using-single-gl_triangle_strip/ which is very similar to my rendering method. However, I am terminating my triangle strip after drawing one row of triangles and starting a new strip at the end.

Below is some sample debug output showing the vertices I am creating:

```
glBegin
drawing vertex ( 0 , 2.76401 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 0 , 1.82236 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 1.55657 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 3.82013 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 3.1032 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 2.77563 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 2.2032 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 4.49317 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 0.469515 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 1.48398 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 0.301526 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 0.606281 , 4 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 1.12292 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 1.98806 , 4 ) 
glEnd/glBegin
drawing vertex ( 0 , 4.31023 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 0 , 2.76401 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 3.64741 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 1.55657 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 2.48897 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 3.1032 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 4.54997 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 2.2032 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 0.11039 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 0.469515 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 1.12043 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 0.301526 , 3 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 4.27371 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 1.12292 , 3 ) 
glEnd/glBegin
drawing vertex ( 0 , 0.818045 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 0 , 4.31023 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 0.886993 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 3.64741 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 0.612948 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 2.48897 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 4.69348 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 4.54997 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 3.56293 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 0.11039 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 2.22925 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 1.12043 , 2 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 0.15616 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 4.27371 , 2 ) 
glEnd/glBegin
drawing vertex ( 0 , 1.84323 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 0 , 0.818045 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 2.28323 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 1 , 0.886993 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 1.1108 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 2 , 0.612948 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 3.72698 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 3 , 4.69348 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 4.41645 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 4 , 3.56293 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 4.69124 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 5 , 2.22925 , 1 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 3.11876 , 0 ) 
drawing vertex ( 6 , 0.15616 , 1 ) 
glEnd
```

And a screenshot of what I am seeing (different vertex values):[image: Gaps!]

I am looking for any clues or insights into what I may be doing wrong. As I stated, I am very new to OpenGL. I am not using the single triangle strip mesh method because I believe it will prove problematic for the final application.

**Update:** I have played around with my y-values and noticed that rendering only seems problematic when I am using random numbers for y generated from

```
qrand() / (float)(RAND_MAX) * 5.0f
```

When using constant values (`y = 1.0f`), `y = x`, or something like `y = z % 2 == 0 ? x : xMax - x`.

Comment: I kind of gave up on my OpenGL issues. Did not have an appropriate book resource to fully learn and understand what was going on. Found a library that does 99% of what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up scrapping my rendering and using a library that provided what I needed (once I got it working). The library, for those interested, is [QwtPlot3D](http://qwtplot3d.sourceforge.net/). It needs some serious performance improvements for my needs, but it has allowed me to bypass this initial hurdle.

Answer (score 0):

A guess:

Do you have face culling enabled?  The order that you send vertices to openGL determine if the triangle is a front face or a back face.  You can control which direction, CW or CCW (CCW is the default) is considered the front face using glFrontFace.

Try disabling face culling; glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE); and see if it fixes your image.

If that does turn out to be your problem, you should keep face culling enabled, but fix the order you send your vertices to openGL.

Comment: any chance you ever set the vertex color to black?  If that's not it, you might need to post code.

Comment: Vertex color is never black.

I am using alpha blending but turning it off doesn't change anything.

I will post some more details later today.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since openGl for me (and then, it was OpenGL-ez on iPod). But the render looks like the strips are not on a regular grid in X,Z. I would reduce the range of the Y (or even set it to 0) to test your triangle strips.

Also, is everything sent as float? I am kinda suspicious of the debug output showing 1,2, etc and not 1.0, 2.0.

Comment: Updated my question based on new findings.

Comment: Gosh, I hope they aren't random for each strip!! But it sounds like sometimes a triangle is 'too steep'. Do you have some level of ambient lighting? And again, reduce the range of Y to something like a reasonable surface, at least to see what is happening.

Comment: I am going to leave it as-is for now and work in some more features. Lighting is on that list. Perhaps it will... shed some light on the situation.